# openmpi python more than 3 prcocesses

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, python

I ran a simple mpi python programm with more than 3 processes.
For example:

```
mpiexec -host master,w1,w2,w3 python code.py
```

There is some error showing that

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname w3: Name or service not known
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.

This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
```

However, if I ran the program with any two of w1,w2,w3, it works.
EX:

```
mpiexec -host master,w1,w3 python code.py
```

And, this is the code

```
 import random
 import numpy as np
 from mpi4py import MPI

 comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
 rank = comm.rank
 size = comm.size

 if rank ==0:
 print rank, 'worker'
 else:
 print rank, 'worker'
```

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the output: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname w3: Name or service not known`, the problem is quite clear:

The hostname `w3` cannot be identified by your master node (machine).
You could add a `name`-`ip` mapping to `/etc/hosts` with the format `ip name`.
For example:

`255.255.255.0  the_name`